# Use php page as backend to connect to database in iphone

Tags: php, ios, json

I want to connect to MySQL server on my web host by iPhone app. In android I used below php page as backend, I connect to this page by json from device and do other things, is it possible on iphone to? is it the same?

login:

```
<?php

require("config.inc.php");

if (!empty($_POST)) {

$query = " SELECT username, password FROM user WHERE username = :username ";

$query_params = array(
    ':username' => $_POST['username']
);

try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error. Please Try Again!";
    die(json_encode($response));

}

$validated_info = false;

$row = $stmt->fetch();
if ($row) {
    if ($_POST['password'] === $row['password']) {
        $login_ok = true;
    }
    else
        $login_ok = false;
}
if ($login_ok == true) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Login Successful";
    die(json_encode($response));
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Invalid Credentials!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}
}
```

Comment: Well the php is just a basic api, it can consumed by any http enabled client. Obviously the IOS Objective-C code will be somewhat different from the Android Java

Comment: I am a web developer, the IOS developer asked me to provide a backend for iphone, what can I do?

Comment: Well if this php api works as expected (as suggested by your comment about using it with android) then all you need to do is properly document it for the IOS dev.

Comment: what do you mean by document it for the IOS dev? I should have change something?

Comment: I mean you have to tell him (or her) how to use this api. There is no guarantee at all that the IOS dev can understand php, any more than you can understand Objective-C, so you will need to write some documentation, such as "to authenticate a user, post credentials to http://example.com/user/auth". Standard api docs will list endpoints, request methods, parameters and responce types.